# VB.Net, XPath and XMLReader - Next and Previous records

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

The below VB.Net code works fine with regards to moving to the next record within the xml file (sampler_01.xml). As you can see, the VB.Net code uses XPath. The problem I am having is getting any logic to work with the "Previous" button (btnPrevious) and getting the previous record.

What I'm really looking to do is have the ability to move next to one record or move back to the previous record. At this point, I'm not sure how the logic needs to be applied. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit: Please see my updated answer below with "Form1.vb 2.0"

"sampler_01.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Companies>
    <Company Id="000001">
        <CompID>000001</CompID>
        <ContFn>Jerry</ContFn>
        <ContLn>McGuire</ContLn>
        <ContEmail>jerrym@email.com</ContEmail>
        <ContPhone>(603) 555-1212</ContPhone>
    </Company>
    <Company Id="000002">
        <CompID>000002</CompID>
        <ContFn>Ben</ContFn>
        <ContLn>Henderson</ContLn>
        <ContEmail>benh@email.com</ContEmail>
        <ContPhone>(603) 882-4040</ContPhone>
    </Company>
    <Company Id="000003">
        <CompID>000003</CompID>
        <ContFn>Bob</ContFn>
        <ContLn>James</ContLn>
        <ContEmail>bobj@email.com</ContEmail>
        <ContPhone>(603) 641-2120</ContPhone>
    </Company>
    <Company Id="000004">
        <CompID>000004</CompID>
        <ContFn>Aaron</ContFn>
        <ContLn>Smith</ContLn>
        <ContEmail>arrons@email.com</ContEmail>
        <ContPhone>(603) 968-1212</ContPhone>
    </Company>
</Companies>
```

"Form1.vb 1.0"

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath

  Public Class Form1

  Dim xpd As XPathDocument
  Dim xpn As XPathNavigator
  Dim xpn1, xpn2, xpn3, xpn4, xpn5 As XPathNodeIterator

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)   Handles MyBase.Load

    LoadXmlToRead()

  End Sub

  Private Sub ListToTextBoxes()

    txtCompID.Text = xpn1.Current.Value
    txtContFn.Text = xpn2.Current.Value
    txtContLn.Text = xpn3.Current.Value
    txtContEmail.Text = xpn4.Current.Value
    txtContPhone.Text = xpn5.Current.Value

  End Sub

  Private Sub LoadXmlToRead()

    xpd = New XPathDocument("C:\XML_Files\sampler_01.xml")
    xpn = xpd.CreateNavigator()

    xpn1 = xpn.Select("/Companies/Company/CompID")
    xpn2 = xpn.Select("/Companies/Company/ContFn")
    xpn3 = xpn.Select("/Companies/Company/ContLn")
    xpn4 = xpn.Select("/Companies/Company/ContEmail")
    xpn5 = xpn.Select("/Companies/Company/ContPhone")

  End Sub

  Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click

    If xpn1.MoveNext() Or _
       xpn2.MoveNext() Or _
       xpn3.MoveNext() Or _
       xpn4.MoveNext() Or _
       xpn5.MoveNext() Then
       ListToTextBoxes()
    Else

    MsgBox("End of contacts has been reached...")
      LoadXmlToRead()
    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As System.Object, e As  System.EventArgs)Handles btnLoad.Click

    LoadXmlToRead()

    If txtCompID.Text = "" And _
       txtContFn.Text = "" And _
       txtContLn.Text = "" And _
       txtContLn.Text = "" And _
       txtContPhone.Text = "" Then

       xpn1.MoveNext()
       xpn2.MoveNext()
       xpn3.MoveNext()
       xpn4.MoveNext()
       xpn5.MoveNext()

       ListToTextBoxes()

       MsgBox("The Contact database has been loaded")
    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click

    If xpn1.Current.MoveToPrevious() Or _
       xpn2.Current.MoveToPrevious() Or _
       xpn3.Current.MoveToPrevious() Or _
       xpn4.Current.MoveToPrevious() Or _
       xpn5.Current.MoveToPrevious() Then

       ListToTextBoxes()

    End If

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to not just load the XML data into some form of collection and just work with that, rather than trying to work against the XML continuously?

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Damien. The reason why I am loading the XML on those instances is so that I can can capture any updates. The above code I've broken down into a simpler format so that others can sample at a local level, but it actually reads the XML from a remote server. However, I really don't see how that works against the XML continuously?

Comment: Hi Damien - by the way, I do see where you are going with your question, but the XML file can get up to about 3 MEG. The XML Reader seems to work a lot faster. If you know of a way to load this into a collection without sacrificing speed, feel free to point me in that direction. The only other thought I had was by serialization, but I haven't gotten that far just yet to test... Again, thanks for your reply...

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for your input as this encouraged me to take a harder look at XMLReader... I found what I was looking for... Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below which uses XML Reader works effectively for what I needed. After some testing with Linq, (as was eloquently suggested by jdweng) I found that XML Reader was a better choice to read larger XML files beyond 1MEG after some redesigning. The below code handles both previous and next controls while capturing any updates when reading XML Files.

"Form1.vb 2.0"

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

      Public dSet = New DataSet
      Public CompRow As Integer

      Private Sub FileLoad()

          dSet.Clear()

          Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
          xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("C:\XML_Files\sampler_01.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
          dSet.ReadXml(xmlFile)

          CompRow = 0
          ShowData(CompRow)

          xmlFile.Close()

      End Sub

      Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

          FileLoad()

      End Sub

      Private Sub btnReLoad_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReLoad.Click

          FileLoad()

      End Sub

      Private Sub ShowData(ByVal CurrentRow)

          txtCompID.Text = dSet.Tables("Company").Rows(CompRow)("CompID").ToString
          txtContFn.Text = dSet.Tables("Company").Rows(CompRow)("ContFn").ToString
          txtContLn.Text = dSet.Tables("Company").Rows(CompRow)("ContLn").ToString
          txtContEmail.Text = dSet.Tables("Company").Rows(CompRow)("ContEmail").ToString
          txtContPhone.Text = dSet.Tables("Company").Rows(CompRow)("ContPhone").ToString

      End Sub

      Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click

          If CompRow <> dSet.Tables("Company").Rows.Count - 1 Then
              CompRow += 1
              ShowData(CompRow)
          Else
              MsgBox("Last Record is Reached!!!")
          End If

      End Sub

      Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click

          If CompRow <> 0 Then
              CompRow -= 1
              ShowData(CompRow)
          Else
              MsgBox("First Record is Reached!!!")
          End If

      End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XML linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Public Class Form1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim companies = doc.Descendants("Company").ToList()

        Dim companyPointer = companies.First()

        Dim index As Integer = 0
        companyPointer = companies(index + 1)
        index = index + 1


    End Sub

End Class
​
```

Comment: Hi jdweng, thanks for the reply. I'll take a look into this later and see how I can implement.

Comment: Hi jdweng, thanks for your suggestion! I was able to take a look at Linq and when comparing large XML files, I found that XML reader was a better option for what I needed. Again, thank you very much for taking the time out to reply! Best!

Comment: Do you mean deserializing the xml into classes?  Or just reading one company at a time?  For huge xml, the recommendation is to use an XML reader for best performance.  If you are going to be searching the xml lots of times, then it is better to read entire xml into classes (deserialize) or into a datatable like Virtual Storm suggested.  I like the datatable method and use it often.  In one instruction you can read entire file.  Then use Linq on datatable to perform queries.